# C# Bitmap set pixel value for Format8bppIndexed

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a Bitmap. I want to change pixel value for all pixels. There is my code :

```
// I use this :
// - int width = 300
// - int height = 400
// - Byte[] matrix = new Byte[width * height]

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        byte pixValue = matrix[y * width + x];
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(pixValue, pixValue, pixValue);
        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, c);
    }
}
```

Before, I used this piece of code with Bitmap Format24bppRgb and it worked fine. Now I use it with Format8bppIndexed and I have error :

> SetPixel is not supported for images with indexed pixel formats.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot use `SetPixel`, you should do something like in your nested `loop`:

```
int width = 300;
int height = 400;
Byte[] matrix = new Byte[width * height];
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    { 
        Color colorBefore = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed); 
        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        bytes[y * data.Stride + x] = 7; 
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(data); 
    }
}
bmp.Save("D:\\imageBimap1.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Isn't it `bytes[x + data.Stride * y]`?

Comment: I've try this but my Image is not correctly saved. It must be the part with `bytes[y * data.Stride + x] `, my `bytes` array length is 53360, my matrix is 52900. What did I miss ?

Comment: I have tested above code, and `imageBimap1.jpg` was created successfully, if your `300*400` `w*h` how the array is `53360` it should be `120000`.

Comment: This code does some very, very strange stuff... LockBits should not be done inside the lowest level of a loop going over all pixels. And the matrix isn't even used...

Comment: Also, colorBefore is never used, meaning you do an expensive `GetPixel` call for no reason, you assign an arbitrary value "7" to every pixel you edit, the entire bitmap is copied into an array and back into the image for _every pixel_ you change, you never change the image's colour palette from the default while the question's code made grayscale colours, and you save the final result as jpeg, which means it is converted back to 24bpp, using lossy compression even.

Comment: This is just a sample to give the clue to OP, there may some problem but at the end it gets work for OP 3 weeks ago !!!!

Comment: ...did you just downvote my answer because I corrected you? :|

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you have an array of bytes, and you want to make an 8-bit image that contains these bytes as gray values. This is actually pretty simple, since the image data you need inside the 8-bit image is exactly the data you already have inside that array. The general process is:

- Create a new 8-bit bitmap with your desired dimensions.
- Using `LockBits` and `Marshal.Copy`, copy the contents of your array into the image data, line by line. Note that the line length inside the `BitmapData` may differ from the actual image width; it's generally rounded up to the next multiple of four bytes. So copy from the start of each line in your array, to the start of each line in the `BitmapData`, using its `Stride` property to know the line width in the data.
- The pixel values in an indexed image are not actually colours; they refer to indices on the image's colour palette. So generate a grayscale palette for your image, from black to white, so every value on your image refers to a colour with that exact same brightness.

In code:

```
public static Bitmap MatrixToGrayImage(Byte[] matrix, Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    // Create a new 8bpp bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    // Get the backing data
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    Int32 dataOffset = 0;
    Int64 scanPtr = data.Scan0.ToInt64();
    // Copy the contents of your matrix into the image, line by line.
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(matrix, dataOffset, new IntPtr(scanPtr), width);
        // Increase input pos by the width, and pos output by the stride.
        dataOffset += width;
        scanPtr += data.Stride;
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    // Get the original palette. Note that this makes a COPY of the ColorPalette object.
    ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;
    // Generate grayscale colours:
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
    // Assign the edited palette to the bitmap.
    bmp.Palette = pal;
    return bmp;
}
```